# Receiving "File not found" error when trying to render animation

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm trying to render an animation, but what i get is the error "File xyz not found".
The directory output is present. I've tried multiple different directories with the same result.

[image]

Anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I messed up the options in my head, you can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

The likely reason this is happening is because there are two menus that seem to do the same thing. But one is to create an animation and the other is to wiew it.But the wording could be confusing.

In the render menu you have two options for viewing either a still image or the animation you already saved.

[image]

Here it does not mean make a View Animation, it means to View An Animation. Confusing because you would expect animation rendering to be here.

You make a Viewpoirt Render of your animation here in the View menu.

[image]

If you use the View Render option from the Render Menu it is looking for a file that you have specified in the output file path. And if you have not made one it will return this error.